# computer vision,extract the features about table,chair,bed...furniture

Tags: c++, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I want to classify the furniture in my house,like table,chair,bed..,by rgb images.

Is there a suitable features extracting algorithm about those furniture?I have extracted the features using moment invariants,but the prediction is not good.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Do you really think there is a ready-made "chair-recognition algorithm" out there ?

Comment: No,I means like this.Like moment invariants,and so on.Would you give me som advice,thank you!

Comment: Then you should give more information about what you want to do and how you imagine it. For the moment, your question is quite vague...

Answer (score 2):

> I want to classify the furniture in my house,like table,chair,bed..,by **rgb images**.

It depends what exactly You want to do. First thing which comes to me is Fuzzy Logic. You can find a lot of different FL libraries in C++:

- LINK: ffll.sourceforge.net/ 
  API looks really nice and 'fast'
- LINK: github.com/fuzzylite/fuzzylite 
  Good implementation with many helpful features

Here You have some proposal:

- http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCE2012/WCE2012_pp713-718.pdf

But first of all You should get some knowledge about Fuzzy Logic, because it can be the triumph of form over substance.

That is why You have to be sure what You want to do exactly.

As alternative You can just identify objects by it's contrast. RGB image to grayscale, then some gamma corrections:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction

...and that's it.

Comment: Thanks for your help!I would learn learn more about fuzzy logic first.